# Dfference between Cordova and react native

Tags: cordova, react-native

I am recently work with Cordova app development its awesome.
Many frontend frameworks and super cool support in stackoverflow:).
Now I heard about react native platform for developing cross platform apps.
My question is what is the major difference between react native and Cordova?

Comment: There was a similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286451/phone-gap-vs-react-native/33290684#33290684

Answer (score 0):

Cordova doesn't actually uses native components like React-native does, and in a case of complex app this is cause some performance issues.