# Moving from Ionic to NativeScript with at least efforts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, nativescript

What is the fastest way to move (migrate app) from Ionic to NativeScript with the least efforts?

- Without rewrite old AngularJS controllers and services.
- And using NativeScript with AngularJS not Angular 2.
- I need to re-write UI with CSS (replacing HTML with XML) only.

**Question is**: Does this applicable? or there is no option but to re-write whole app!
If yes, what the path that I have to follow to make it?

---

The story if you want to know why I want to do this:

I have a mobile application that based on Ionic (ionic 1 with AngularJS), Ionic is really nice platform to build app, but a lot of headache specially with performance challenges, in my App I have a really an issue with this through many devices, until I found NativeScript which is really awesome, so I'm thinking about move my current live app from Ionic to NativeScript.

Until now, as I see seems I have to re-write whole app from scratch, but this is costly and not an option for me, I was searching in internet and found no clear answers, even in documentation they seems only using Angular2 with TS (which is better but not have time for this now) or just plan JavaScript.

This is good side reference: [Lost in hybrid app frameworks like Ionic, Cordova,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639688/lost-in-hybrid-app-frameworks-like-ionic-cordova/35664593#35664593)

Comment: I think this question is way too broad to be addressed in this format, but I'll add my opinion here....  I don't know how you would get away with not re-writing your angular app from scratch if you are completely replacing HTML with XML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put you can't. Angular 1 is dependent on the DOM. With NativeScript there is no DOM. Which is why you have performance issues in the webview. You need to just bite the bullet and rewrite it with ng2 you'll thank yourself later. The webview is your downfall with your performance on Cordova and to get away from that you'll have better performance and the perf benefits you get with ng2 are also very nice. Heres a link with some good info on ionic 2 to NativeScript but that's as good as it gets. Because you can't easily from Cordova webview app to native UI like NativeScript or react native. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/05/converting-ionic-2-mobile-app-nativescript/

Here's someone who just went ionic 2 to NativeScript and commented on the slack channel https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/archives/general/p1471789794013989 join the slack channel for some really awesome community help if you decide to do it.