# Is React Native a Native, Hybrid, Mixture of both or any other kind of technology/framework?

Tags: react-native

I have read many blog posts, Quora questions etc about "Is React Native a Native, Hybrid, Mixture of both or any other kind of technology/framework?" like as given in the below section.

Some of these says that it is a Native Framework and some says it is a Hybrid Framework. I want to know what exactly is the type of the React-Native Framework?

https://www.quora.com/Is-React-Native-actually-native-or-hybrid

https://technostacks.com/blog/native-app-vs-hybrid-app/

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-React-Native-and-Hybrid-Apps

https://www.quora.com/Is-React-Native-actually-native

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-know-if-a-mobile-app-is-native-hybrid-or-React-Native

[Technological difference between react-native and cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128899/technological-difference-between-react-native-and-cordova)

Answer (score 1):

React Native has received a lot of attention, and developers are enthusiastic about it. The technology extends all that is fantastic about React.js to apps, allowing developers to create native mobile apps using JavaScript, resulting in improved app experiences.

**How better React Native is and what it promises?**

React Native is a framework that creates native apps for iOS and Android devices. React takes over the view controller and uses JavaScript to create native views programmatically. Instead of hitting browsers, it focuses on web platforms. To put it another way, web developers are at ease writing mobile apps that look and sound native, all using the JavaScript library. The advantage of this framework is that most of the code you write can be spread across platforms, making it simple to build for both Android and iOS at the same time.

This means you can have all the speed and the power of a native application, with the ease of development that comes with React. The two main reasons are:

- With React Native your application logic is written and runs in
  JavaScript, whereas your application UI is fully native; therefore
  you have none of the compromises typically associated with HTML5 UI.
- React introduces a novel, radical, and highly functional approach to
  constructing user interfaces. In brief, the application UI is simply
  expressed as a function of the current application state.

**React Native Bridging Gaps**

React Native programs, including React for the Web, are written with JSX, a combination of JavaScript and XML-Esque mark-up. React Native supports both iOS and Android and has the ability to extend to all future platforms. React Native can be used to create production-ready mobile apps that use actual mobile UI components rather than web-views and look and sound like any other mobile app. It also exposes JavaScript interfaces for platform APIs, allowing the React Native apps to access platform features such as the phone camera and the user's location, enhancing the user experience.

React Native is getting close to bridging the gap between native app success and web app development ease. When most frameworks attempt to imitate native UI elements, the results are typically a little off; reverse-engineering all the fine details of items like animations take a lot of time and effort, and the results can easily become outdated. React Native, on the other hand, converts your markup into true, native UI components, leveraging existing rendering methods on whatever platform you're using.

Furthermore, since React runs independently of the main UI thread, your app will maintain high performance without losing functionality. React Native follows the same update period as React: when props or state change, React Native re-renders the views. The main difference between React Native and React in the browser is that React Native uses the host platform's UI libraries rather than HTML and CSS markup to achieve this.

**Developer Comfort Zone**

This means that developers who are used to working on the web with React can create mobile apps that have the output and look and feel of native apps while still using familiar tools. In two other fields, React Native outperforms traditional mobile development: developer experience and cross-platform development ability.

For hybrid mobile development, React Native brings all of React.JS’s better app performance, DOM abstraction (as well as manipulation in the virtual DOM), and streamlined programming methods – pace and agility of web app development with native results.

React Native lets you link the plugin with a native module, so you can link the map up with the device’s functions like zoom, rotate, and the compass, while using less memory and loading faster. If your app supports older operating systems (and older devices), this can help you keep the app running smoothly. Getting started with React Native is easy—especially for JavaScript pros.

In short, React Native aims to primarily bring the power of the React programming model to mobile app development. It is the future generation framework.

Answer (score -1):

React Native is a hybrid framework

Comment: Can you please elaborate, why it is a hybrid framework?