# Cordova or ReactNative. Which should i prefer for this specific project?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, mobile, react-native

I am working on a project that needs to be cross platform for web and mobile. Currently the website is being developed using ReactJS and cordova is being used to make it available on mobile.

But I was wondering if it would maybe be a better choice to use ReactNative for the mobile version because cordova might be more of a hassle than ReactNative is. I dont know if this is true tho.

I know this is kind of an open question that tends to be opinionated but i'd still like to hear some thoughts on this from you guys because its bugging me and I dont have the knowledge and experience of working on both these platforms (cordova and reactnative) to have an educated opinion.

Answer (score 1):

React Native is an abstraction to write native UIs for Android and iOS. Your JS code runs in a JS runtime on the OS, but the UI is rendered as native components. This makes it very different than Cordova.

With React Native, you can use the standard platform components such as UITabBar on iOS and Drawer on Android. This gives your app a consistent look and feel with the rest of the platform ecosystem, and keeps the quality bar high. These components are easily incorporated into your app using their React component counterparts, such as TabBarIOS and DrawerLayoutAndroid.

Also you can find differences here:

https://www.toptal.com/mobile/comparing-react-native-to-cordova

[Phone gap vs React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286451/phone-gap-vs-react-native)

http://noeticforce.com/mobile-app-development-cordova-vs-react-native-vs-xamarin